# change ascii code and preappend character to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I want to pre-append a character to a string after performing some calculations to the character ascii code but doing `(somenumber+'0') + s` doesn't work and I don't understand why.

the answer I want is "ahello" using the ascii representation of a ('0' + 49)

This is what I have tried:

```
std::string s = "hello";
s.insert(0, std::to_string('a'));
std::cout << s << std::endl; // 97hello

s = "hello";
s += 'a';
std::cout << s << std::endl; // helloa

s = "hello";
s = 'a' + s;
std::cout << s << std::endl; // ahello

//s = (49+'0') + s;
//std::cout << s << std::endl;
```

Comment: To_string actually coverts 'a' as a byte to string,which is "97". In c++, 'a' is 97, not "a".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to append the ASCII code int of the character (97) or do you want to append the ASCII representation ('a') ?

In the later case, you could just use `s.insert(0, "a")` directly.

If you want to transform the ASCII code int before, you can use the std::string [fill constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/), as was already pointed out by Steephen:

```
// fills the string with n consecutive copies of character c.
std::string(size_t n, char c); 

// so you could do this to get a string "f":
std::string(1, 'a'+5);
```

Comment: the ascii representation

Comment: the other answers should answer your question by now :)

Answer (score 1):

This will solve the issue:

```
 s.insert(0, string(1,1+'a'));
```

O/p

bhello

```
s.insert(0, string(1,0+'a'));
```

O/P

ahello

Comment: I don't want to do that though ... I need to do something with '0' + some number and append that to the front

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  s.insert(0, string(1,49+'a'));
```